# Keep hover box when click in Plotly.js

Tags: plotly, plotly.js

I am plotting two curves in Plotly and I need to when a user clicks anywhere, it keeps the hover box until it is clicked again.

I am aware of the 'plotly_click' event, but no success keeping the hover box yet. Any ideas?

I intend to keep it like the following figure

[image: My plotly hoverbox]